# how to debug tests in .net

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, nunit

I want to debug my tests, to examine every test to see where exactly is fail. I was using coderush which is awesome tool but my trial period 1month is expired.

Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: "I was using coderush which is awesome tool but my trial period 1month is expired." If you think it's awesome, why not buy it?!

Comment: What is stopping you from debugging your tests ? Is it a test runner for NUnit you need ?

Comment: http://testdriven.net/ is a great runner, and is free for personal use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Mark says, if you find a tool really useful, buy it. Personally I use ReSharper to run my tests, but that's a personal choice.

I *also* use [NCrunch](http://www.ncrunch.net/), which is free (and wonderful).  I believe you can use that for debugging too.

However, you can debug with the NUnit GUI - just attach the debugger to the process, set breakpoints and run the tests.

However, I'd typically try *not* to require using the debugger to fix tests. When an assertion fails in a well-designed test, that *usually* gives enough information to fix the implementation, after a bit of thought. If it doesn't, that suggests it's a complicated scenario - which sometimes suggests adding more tests to handle each part of the scenario. But yes, occasionally you will need the debugger...

Comment: I'll give it a shot to NCrunch. Thanks though