# How do I debug a failing test method in NCrunch

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2015, ncrunch

I am using NCrunch to run tests in my project and have a test method that is failing, which looks like this:

[image: Test method failing in NCrunch]

> Is there any way I can debug this method and if so how?

In [this StackOverFlow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11168526/3213157) Jon Skeet mentions you can "attach the debugger to the process" but I do not know how to do this - could anyone tell me how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is quite straightforward. You can do 1 of several things:

- Right click on any of the red dots and choose 'Debug covering tests in new task runner process' (this might run several tests if more than 1 test covers that line ie if you click on a dot in the source code under test rather than the code in the actual test)
- Right click on the red '>' and choose 'Debug starting tests in new task runner process' (this will only run one test, but this starting point is only available in the actual test)
- In the tests windows (ctrl-shift-m) click the test then right click and choose 'Debug selected tests in new task runner process'
- In the tests windows (ctrl-shift-m) click the test and select the little 'bug' icon on the toolbar at the top.